# How to configure the Android Emulator to show onscreen buttons like the new Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I would like to convert/adapt my application to Android 4.0.
To do so I plan to use the ActionBar on devices that support it. 
All Android version >= 3.0 do so. Furthermore devices that do not have a hardware menu button seem to show an "menu" button on the actionbar automatically.

When I test my application on the emulator using API level 13 this does work as expected...
... but somehow I'm not able to setup the emulator to behave the same way while emulating a phone on API level 14 (Android 4.0). 
When I try to set "**Hardware Back/Home keys**" to **false** there are **no buttons** at all (not on the screen and not keypad provided by the emulator).

I have seen on some screenshots and videos from the "Galaxy Nexus" that it is showing an "menu" button on the ActionBar as well ... like Honeycomb tablets do it, but I'm somehow not successful to do the same with the emulator which makes it a bit more complicated to understand how my UI will work on Andoid 4.0 phones.

**EDIT:**
[Here is an image that is showing the On-Screen back and home buttons I would like to see in the emulator:](http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/8-buttons.jpg)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems the issue was fixed with the latest update of the SDK (R16).
Just update your SDK and ADT to R16 and create a new emulator using the updated Android 4.0 system image.

Comment: I have tried this with an updated (to R16) SDK, and it still does not show the navigation buttons. Did you do anything differently?

Comment: I currently have installed in the latest version of the Eclipse plugin (16.0.1). 
All I have to do to make the on screen buttons work, is to create a new AVD and set the hardware property "Hardware Back/Home keys" of this system to "No" before I launch it the first time.

Answer (score 14):

The soft keys showed up for me when I set `hw.mainKeys` to `no`:

1. Open `$HOME/.android/avd/YOURS.avd/config.ini`
2. Set `hw.mainKeys=no`

(This was covered in [a deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049501/238753); don't know why it was deleted.)

Comment: Thanks really helpful answer

Comment: Great answer, it works. In my case I wanted to hide the software buttons (home, back, menu), so I used `hw.mainKeys=yes`. That worked for me too.

Comment: where do i use this command? what is "$HOME" exactly?

Answer (score 4):

When you create new emulator there is grid **Hardware**, and there you can add options **Hardware home and back buttons** and **Hardware keyboard**. So, create new emulator and look at your "Galaxy Nexus" :)

Unfortunately you can't change this properties for existing emulator.

Comment: Can you give me little bit more details on what you did (step by step). Which skin are you using WXGA720?

As mentioned in my question I'm aware of the "hardware grid" and I've already set Hardware Back/Home keys to false and also a lot other keyboard related parameter.
Unfortunately without success.

The config.ini of this emulator does have **hw.mainKeys=no, skin.name=WXGA720, hw.keyboard.lid=no, hw.keyboard=no**

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to R16 I could only get the on-screen buttons to appear if I created an emulator using the **WXGA720** resolution.

Here is my complete config.ini file:

```
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.lcd.density=320
disk.cachePartition.size=256MB
hw.cpu.arch=arm
skin.name=WXGA720
sdcard.size=512M
abi.type=armeabi-v7a
image.sysdir.2=system-images\android-16\armeabi-v7a\
image.sysdir.1=add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-16\images\armeabi-v7a\
hw.gps=yes
skin.path=platforms\android-16\skins\WXGA720
hw.keyboard.lid=no
hw.cpu.model=cortex-a8
vm.heapSize=48
hw.ramSize=1024
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: `hw.mainKeys=no` is the key for the soft nav button to show up

Answer (score 0):

If your application includes functionality that would respond to a menu button, the menu button will be added to the black bottom bar.

If you are having trouble seeing this in the emulator, you can do a bit of a workaround by setting it to a tablet resolution (I use 1280x800) and observing your menu button behavior there, as it should be the same as on the phone version.

Comment: The mentioned menu button will only appear if your application does not include the ActionBar. Has my app is tablet compatible it does use the ActionBar on all devices with API level 11 and higher. 
I would like to have an idea how the "overflow menu" does change the look of this ActionBar on devices with a smaller screen as a tablet.

I did try all those "workarounds" but until now I did notsee this onscreen buttons when using an Android 4.0 emulator and a phone like skin.
if a tablet skin is used, the onscreen buttons are ok but the screen arrange does look like a tablet not a like phone.

Comment: Menu button appears only if your target sdk is less than Android 3.0